# Eclipse c++ class generation formating

Tags: c++, eclipse, generator, eclipse-cdt

I've switched to Eclipse Mars.1 and I can't figure out how to fix this.

Here's the problem:

I right click on the subfolder MySubFolder and choose New->Class

In Class name field I enter MyClass and fill the namespace with MySubFolder and click on Finish

The generated .cpp has the partner include surounder with angle bracket and full path :

```
#include <MySubFolder/MyClass.h>
```

I want it that way :

```
#include "MyClass.h"
```

I tried ticking C/C++->Code Style->Include Style->Closely Related Headers->Partner Header->Use path relative to the including file

And made sure "Use angle bracket" was not set for the same option but none will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "`src`" directory in your include paths you are passing to the compiler.

For example if I have `"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src}"` listed in my include paths like this:

[image]
then CDT uses angle brackets relative to `"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src}"` to calculate include directory.

You may also have the include paths in the auto-discovered or manually managed section if you are not using CDT's managed build projects (e.g. you write your own makefiles, or use tools like cmake), like this:

[image]

If you create a class not within any include directory, it uses double-quotes.

Comment: This is actually what I do, and every thing is fine about location and namespace, even if I create it at the root I got angle bracket #include  <MyClass.h>

Comment: Rewrote answer completely based on properly understanding your problem.

Comment: I don't have this tab under settings but I removed the current workspace from C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes->GNU C++ and it fixed the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @GARCINDavid OK, if you don't have that setting it is probably because you are not using CDT Managed Projects, but using your own build system (e.g. makefiles, cmake, etc). In that case the paths in "C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes->GNU C++" were discovered automatically by the build and discovery and may return depending on your set-up. If you have something like `g++ -I proj/src` in your makefile, then that is the same essential rule as what I had in the picture. Best of luck, and feel free to upvote/accept my answer if it is correct.

Comment: I found out I don't get the current project include completion using #include <> syntax anymore... Is there any way to get it back without having the above mentioned problem ?

Comment: That sounds like working as expected. (over simplifying slightly) the <> syntax is for things relative to explicit includes and "" for relative to source includes. If I am not understanding :-) then please ask a new question (tagged with eclipse-cdt) and I (and others!) will see it.